# Writing files into a directory which still does not exists

Tags: java, windows, file-io

I'm using this script on **WINDOWS**

```
public void copyFile(File sourceDirectory, File targetFile, File targetDirectory) throws IOException{
    String temp = targetFile.getAbsolutePath();
    String relativeD = temp.substring(sourceDirectory.getAbsolutePath().length(), targetFile.getAbsolutePath().length());
    String rootD = sourceDirectory.getName();
    String fullPath = targetDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + rootD + relativeD;
    File fP = new File( fullPath );
    System.out.println("PATH: " + fullPath);
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(targetFile).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream( fP ).getChannel();
    int maxCount = (64 * 1024 * 1024) - (32 * 1024);
    long size = inChannel.size();
    long position = 0;
    while (position < size) {
            position += inChannel.transferTo(position, maxCount, outChannel);
     }
    if (inChannel != null) inChannel.close();
    if (outChannel != null) outChannel.close();
}
```

What I'm doing is simple. I need to copy a file from a location to another but I have to keep the directories they're in.

So with `relativeD` I'm taking something like this: *dir/files.sql* or simply *files.sql*.

This is happening because for specific directories I need to copy them recursively respecting the tree structure.

The problem is this method is not working. I don't know why because if I use a simple

```
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream( new File( targetDirectory, targetFile ) ).getChannel();
```

it works. I suppose this is happening because in this case it's copying the file under an existing directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [article](http://webxadmin.free.fr/article/create-recursive-folders-with-java-1070.php) (top Google search hit for 'java mkdir recursive'):

> Have a look at the java.io.File : it does the job perfectly, with the mkdirs function :
>
> ```
>     new File("c:/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd").mkdirs();
> ```

Comment: ok I'll try but my File is something like: D:\somethingExisting\DirectoryToCreate\NewFile.sql s it gonna work?

Comment: Ok it works but in a really weird coded way. What I have to do is to create the fP file, then create a new file from fP.getParent() and operate a mkdirs() on this one.